# Process Builder: Error when trying to define criteria

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, process-builder

I have cloned an already created process and I am trying to modify the Criteria for this Action Group. But when I click on criteria it shows me this error. [image]

Comment: Can you share the existing criteria? Most probably the criteria contain a reference to the field or other metadata which is modified or deleted.